# Codeigniter read from directory failed

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, readdir, opendir

I changed and now it does not show nothing. The directories exist on the folder.

i am giving you an example. If i echo $dir i get fullurlpath/root_folder/username

the whole path and directories exist so the $dir is ok, something else must happend.

class Front_Page extends CI_Model{

```
function front_display(){

    $this->db->select('id, username');
    $query = $this->db->get('models')->result();

    $display_models = '<ul class="display-models">';

    foreach ($query as $row){


        $username= $row->username;

        $dir = base_url('/img/'.$username.'');
        echo $dir;
        if(is_dir($dir)){
            if($dh = opendir($dir)){
                while(($file = readdir($dh)) !== FALSE){            

                    $display_models .= '<li>';
                    $display_models .= '<a href="profilepage/'.$row->id.'">';
                    $display_models .= '<img src="'.$dir.'/'.$file.'">';
                    $display_models .= '</a>';
                    $display_models .= '</li>';

                }

                closedir($dh);
            }
        }
    }

        $display_models .= '</ul>';

        return $display_models;
}
```

}

Comment: Echo out what the directory path shows. Remember to check to see if it exists first before opening it. Remember if it is relative the path is starting at the root of your index file.

Comment: When i echo $dir it shows http://localhost/my_root_folder/  and when i echo $img_dir it shows Resource id #45,Resource id #46 ect... which are not same as my database id

Comment: What is the directory structure from the root of your website to the folder containing the images?

Comment: http://localhost/root_folder/img/username/images.jpg

Comment: You need to opendir() on a path like ('root_folder/img/username') or if that doesn't work remove the root_folder path so just img/username of course username would by replaced by the variable.

Comment: actually looking at this why are you ever using opendir(), that is not what you want the way you are using the code. opendir opens a handler to the folder so you could loop through all the files within but you are not using it like that. http://us2.php.net/opendir  If you are just making your open link to a file you don't need opendir() at all.

Comment: No i want to read the files that are within that directory. I changed the dir: $dir = base_url();
            $img_dir = opendir(base_url('img/'.$username.''));
            
            echo $dir,  $img_dir;       it gives me an error: Message: opendir(http://localhost/root_folder/img/username): failed to open dir: not implemented

Comment: In that case try the 2 path suggestions above and look at the example (on the php.net link above) of how they loop through the directory handler once it is opened.

Comment: If you see above i edited my post and now is giving me another type of error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is sayings the path is not found, it has to exists first. The second problem is that you are using the code the wrong way even when the path is fixed.

```
// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            $display_models .= '<li>';
    $display_models .= '<a href="profilepage/'.$row->id.'">';
    $display_models .= '<img src="'. $dir.'/'. $file.'">';
    $display_models .= '</a>';
    $display_models .= '</li>';
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
```

You will want something similar to the above, that is how you use that function.

Remember that the path needs to be fixed first otherwise this will not loop through anything because the folder was not found and it will not find any files to loop through.

Comment: Still having problem, you can see above that i changed as you suggested but still something wrong.

Comment: Ok i think i fixed the problem. $dir needed to be the folder that handle the images and not the full url path. Thank you Danny.